# Neural Network Underfitting with Dogs and Cats

Tags: neural-network, training-data, bias-neuron

Without necessarily getting into the code of it, but focusing more on the principles, I have a question about what I assume would be underfitting.

If I am training a network that recognizes true or false as to whether an image is of a dog, and I have maybe 40,000 images, where all dog images are labeled as 1, and all other images are labeled as 0 - what can I do to assure accuracy so that, if only maybe 5,000 of those images are dogs, the network does not act “lazily” from its training, and also label dogs as closer to 0 than 1?

For example, the main purpose of this question is to be able to recognize with high accuracy if an image really is of a dog, without really caring too much about the other images, other than the fact that they are not of dogs. Also, I would like to be able to retain the probability that the guess is correct, because this is highly important for my purposes.

The only two things I was able to come up with were to:

1. Have more nodes in the network, or
2. Have half of the images be of dogs (so use 10,000 images where 5,000 of them are dogs).

But I think this 2nd option might give dogs a disproportionately large chance of being the output of the testing data, which would destroy the accuracy and the whole purpose of this network.

I am sure this has been addressed before, so even a point in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a binary classification task where both classes appear with different frequency in your dataset. About 1/8 is "dog" and 7/8 is "no dog".

1. In order to avoid biased learning towards one or the other class, it is important that you [stratify](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation) your training, validation and test data so that these fractions are kept across every subset.
2. You say that you want to "retain the probability" that the guess is correct - I assume you mean you want to evaluate the "dogness"-probability as output variable. That's a simple [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) output layer with two outputs: 1st is "dog", 2nd "not dog". It's the typical way to address classification problems, regardless of the number of classes you need to distinguish.

Comment: Thanks! Could it also be a problem with underfitting if it is not good at recognizing dogs, and spits out an answer closer to 0 than 1, for every time it is tested on dogs?

Comment: If you keep having a problem fitting your model, I'd rather say it might either be (1) a problem with image data preparation, i.e. do your [standardize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) your data well, or (2) a problem of your overall architecture - in this case I'd say stick with proven models from the literature instead of creating your own (if you're not already doing this anyway)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.